# style tag inside svg use

Tags: html, svg

i have an svg that use a symbol but style tag no affect styles the only workaround that i found is inline styles

exists an easy way to do that?

code in html

```
<svg><use xlink:href="img/push.svg#push_icon"></use></svg>
```

code in push.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
  <style>
  .st1 {
      fill: red;
  }
  </style>
            <symbol id="push_icon" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="enable-background:new 0 0 250 250;">
...
</symbol>

        </defs>


</svg>
```

Comment: The selector in your stylesheet, `.st1`, will select an element within the SVG with `class="st1"`; in your SVG you have no element with that class, so of course it won't work. What did you expect?

Comment: That, and `enable-background` has been deprecated since atleast 2014 see https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#AccessBackgroundImage

Comment: st1 element is not in the example but exists in real code

Comment: CSS rules do not cross document boundaries.  So you can't restyle the `st1` class from the parent document.